# how to use ajax to post to local server?

Tags: android, jquery, node.js, ajax, cordova

Trying to do my first nodejs project.

I have built a web-based server using Nodejs, which runs at localhost:3000/home.

Then I used Cordova to build an android app and run on an emulator. I tried to send the query to the server and get the search results back to show on the app. However, I get problems in using ajax and I have tried many expressions of the url, it all came out: file not found.

The project hierarchy:

[image: hierarchy]

post function in homecontroller.js (using express and ejs)

```
  app.post('/home', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
         var rsults = [];
         var pname = req.body.player_name;
         var tname = req.body.team_name;
         results[] = searchdatabase(pname,tname);
        res.render('home', {results: results});
```

in the app: index.html

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="player_name"name="player_name">
 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="team_name" name="team_name">
               
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="search">Search</button>

<script>
  function search(){
  var pname = $("[name='player_name']").val();
  var tname = $("[name='team_name']").val();
    
  jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost:3000/home",
     data: '{"pname": "pname", "tname": "tname"}',
     dataType: "json",
     cache: false,
     sucess: function(response)
     {alert("sent");}
     })
     }
</script>
</form>
```

This code is poor, maybe what I wrote in the server isn't corresponding to the ajax request from the app, or I am doing something wrong with the ajax function. Please suggest a solution to achieve the purpose, as the the web sever runs well.

Comment: So your server is hosted on your mobile device as well?

Comment: no, I just tried it on the device web browser an find it use 10.0.2.2 instead of  localhost. Just want to provide more info about it. The app actually only need to retrieve data from sever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localhost is recognized by a device as itself, meaning that if you host a server on your computer, and you communicate on your computer to that server, you can use localhost.

However, if you run your website on a different device, let's say your phone, localhost is interpreted as itself by that device, meaning it obviously does not communicate to your computer.

Now in order for two devices to find eachother, they need to know eachothers name, i.e. IP address. If both devices are in the same network (your local WiFi for instance), you can use their local IP's as a way to communicate between them.

Get the local IP of your computer by opening a command prompt and typing ipconfig if you are on windows, or type ip addr if you are on Linux. Use the IP you find (ipv4) as the address you post to (basically replace `localhost` with the IP you found). Then try again.

Comment: I tried url: "http://myIP:3000/home"; but still coms out the same error: "application error, net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///home). Both the the sever and emulator run on the same computer and when I open a brower and type 10.0.2.2:3000/home(someone said it is android localhost), the web sever can also work.

Comment: Let's say your computer's IP is 52.120.71.160 for example (it isn't of course, check your ipconfig). Then you need to connect to: 'http://52.120.71.160:3000/home'. The 10.0.2.2 address is a clever way to connect to localhost on the host machine of the emulator. However, this will never work if you deploy the app to an actual mobile device.